# CPU bottleneck Xeon 3104 with RTX A4000 when using PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, nvidia, bottleneck

I am looking to upgrade an older machine we have at our lab to use for deep learning (PyTorch) in addition to my personal work station. Its an older Dell work station but the relevant specs are as follows:

```
PSU: 950W
RAM: 64 GB DDR4 ECC
CPU: Xeon Bronze 3104 @1.7 GHz
```

It even has an older NVIDIA GPU I can use for display output when the A4000 is fully loaded like I currently do on my personal setup.

Through the university we can acquire a RTX A4000 (I know not best price to performance), which is basically a 3070ti with more VRAM. I am concerned that the low clock speeds may cause a bottle neck. Does anyone have experience with a similar configuration?

Thank you for the help!